# VSCode - debugger not hitting break-point on postman request

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, postman

I'm building an `express.js` application that I'm testing using `Postman`. I haven't needed debugging until now, but I've just tried to set it up and run into a bit of an issue.

I followed [this tutorial](https://emcain.github.io/vscode-debugger/), but it isn't working for me as the end result of the tutorial shows that it should.

I built myself a `launch.json` file with a configuration built to handle running using `nodemon`...

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "nodemon",
        "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
        "restart": true,
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    },
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\bin\\www"
    }
]
```

I then started the debugger and got the following output in my terminal...

> C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.cmd --inspect=35939 --debug-brk app.js
>
> [nodemon] 1.14.11
>
> [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
>
> [nodemon] watching: *.*
>
> [nodemon] starting `node --inspect=35939 --debug-brk app.js`
>
> Debugger listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:35939/fca1b410-e096-4189-a5b2-bf266755e89e
>
> For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
>
> Debugger attached.
>
> (node:24832) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --inspect
>   --debug-brk` is deprecated. Please use `node --inspect-brk` instead.

To test it out, I put a break-point on the very first line of my `app.js` file. The break-point was hit successfully.

I went into the router file and put a break-point inside the post method that I needed to debug...

```
//POST New Trip page//
router.post('/newtrip', function (req, res) {
    return tripCtrl.create(req, res); <---- BP on this line
});
```

I then ran the `Postman` request that I have been using to test this method:

> (POST) http://localhost:3000/newtrip

I was fully expecting my new break-point to be hit, but the break-point wasn't hit, and I got no output from my debugger console or terminal. All I have is `Postman` returning 'Could not get any response'.

I'm well and truly lost as to where to go. Can anyone spot what might be wrong here please?

This is my file structure for the project:

[image: project file structure]

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Not really familiar with your setup here, but it looks like you have postman sending requests on port 3000 and the debugger is listening on port 35939.  Maybe change your postman request to use port 35939?

Comment: Remove `.launch` folder and hit F5 again, It'll start debugging using your `start` command in `package.json`

Comment: @kgangadhar just tried both of these solutions and had a different outcome. The `postman` request ran, the BP still wasn't hit and the response body to `postman` was the words "Websockets request was expected". Does this mean anything to you?

Comment: if there is any start command in `package.json` can u please update it

Comment: Postman is sending a `http` request and your listener is looking for a `ws` (websockets request).  So that is getting rejected for an invalid protocol it seems.

Comment: @kgangadhar my start command is `"node ./bin/www"`. What should this be changed to?

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimum configuration of `lanuch.json` required to debug in vscode based on your start command. Try updating with this to debug.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/www"
        }
    ]
}
```